# Apache Returns 403 forbidden

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, slim, elastic-load-balancer

I have API Project written in PHP 7.0.22 using Slim 3.0 framework.
The app API is running on AWS (EC2) server using the elastic load balancer with Ubuntu 14.04.5, Apache 2.4.7.

Most of the time the requests return a valid response
but some of them return a "403 forbidden" (the same requests that return a valid response)

I checked the Apache logs but there's nothing there.
I think the blockage comes from the server.

I tried to find out if there is any kind of module which can cause this. but i did not find the problem.
list of modules :

```
Array
(
    [0] => core
    [1] => mod_so
    [2] => mod_watchdog
    [3] => http_core
    [4] => mod_log_config
    [5] => mod_logio
    [6] => mod_version
    [7] => mod_unixd
    [8] => mod_access_compat
    [9] => mod_alias
    [10] => mod_auth_basic
    [11] => mod_authn_core
    [12] => mod_authn_file
    [13] => mod_authz_core
    [14] => mod_authz_host
    [15] => mod_authz_user
    [16] => mod_autoindex
    [17] => mod_deflate
    [18] => mod_dir
    [19] => mod_env
    [20] => mod_evasive20
    [21] => mod_filter
    [22] => mod_mime
    [23] => prefork
    [24] => mod_negotiation
    [25] => mod_php5
    [26] => mod_rewrite
    [27] => mod_setenvif
    [28] => mod_socache_shmcb
    [29] => mod_ssl
    [30] => mod_status
)
```

Where can this blockage come from?

Comment: This may get an answer quicker in a server-based Stack Exchange site, If you're using EC2 then implies there are multiple servers running your code so perhaps one of them isn't set up correctly. ?

Comment: @Martin  there is only one server that ruining in this time

Comment: What specific requests return a 403?